# Need to make 3 colums and 3 rows of <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm really bad with CSS and can't figure it out how to do it like this,it should be fixed, if you change width,height of browser  it's still would be 3 rows and 3 columns, note that can't change html.

Any ideas ? Included picture what I would like to see.

[3 rows and 3 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoCDF.jpg)

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
       <div class"column"></div>
</div>

.column {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution with CSS

```
.row .column {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 33.333%;
  min-height: 50px; //or whatever
}
```

The key here is `display:inline-block`.

Comment: `float: left; width: 33.333%` would work better due to the whitespace issue with inline block which will cause them to wrap inconsistently ([see here](https://jsfiddle.net/2kLy8haj/))

Comment: [Setting `font-size: 0` on the container](https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/2kLy8haj/1/) and resetting it for each child is the workaround for inconsistent whitespace, but it's hacky...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/, its ideal for this kind of thing!

Once you include bootstrap in your site you can do something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```